# Names disintct in linq

Tags: linq, distinct

I try to select name but there is names which is repeat now i want to select these through distinct how i done this in linq

```
string data2 = "[";
T1 DB = new T1();
var te = DB.tblVni;

foreach (var c in te)
{
    data2 += "'" + c.Name + "',";
}

data2 = data2.Substring(0, data2.Length - 1);
data2 += "]";
```

this return me like this

['DPSB','MV','PSB','','','','PSB','PSB','','PSB','PSB','MV','','','MV','PSB','','MV','MV','MV','','PSB','MV',

where as i dont want to repeat these names

any solution

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but you shouldn't be manually building JSON. There are much better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace

```
foreach (var c in te)
{
    data2 += "'" + c.Name + "',";
}
```

by the following snippet.

```
foreach (var c in te.Select( x => x.Name ).Distinct())
{
    data2 += "'" + c + "',";
}
```

You could also use the existing facilities and rewrite the entire part as

```
T1 DB = new T1();
var te = DB.tblVni;

string data2
    = String.Format("[{0}]",
          String.Join( ",", te.te.Select( x => x.Name ).Distinct() ) );
```

which would not require the manual removal of the terminal comma. However, in total, indeed Json should not be generated manually, there are existing tools for that, like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data2 = String.Format("[{0}]", te.Select(i => i.Name).Distinct().Aggregate((v, n) => String.Format("'{0}','{1}'", v,n)));
```

Output:

```
['DPSB','MV','PSB']
```